# Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment

I am new to Rails. I have my rails application and now I want to deploy it. What do i need to deploy my rails application? Do i need an IAS server or Apache would do it all? I am very confused because I have never deployed any website before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails will run on a variety of different servers and configurations nowadays. [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is one that is very popular that supports Apache or the Nginx web server. Mongrel and Thin are also commonly used.

You don't say whether you have a specific host in mind. For a newcomer especially, I can't recommend [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) highly enough. You can create a free account with them and deploy very easily. Essentially you check your code into a Git repository hosted by Heroku, register your application with them through their command line interface and then you can deploy. The entire process literally only takes a few minutes.

- I recommend that you take a look at Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/book) which has a section (1.4) on deployment to Heroku and also covers using Git amongst other topics

If you are hosting your application on your own server then be aware that [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/i) is pretty much the standard tool for creating repeatable deployments of Rails applications. Slicehost have an [excellent series of detailed articles](http://articles.slicehost.com/rails) that cover pretty much every aspect of deploying a Rails application to your own server.

Comment: +1 If you have to ask how to host, you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Sounds like Heroku would be a good fit for you.

Another fairly easy option is Engineyard for a larger/ more complicated site. It is more expensive but has a support option to help you over any hurdles you may encounter.